# Email Template file

Tags: magento-1.9

I have 1 field (order no), it is optional field, if some one fill order no then it is easy to get in template file like  `

```
Order No : {{var order_no}} }}`
```

But if it is not fill by someone then email template file show blank order no like (in a mail)

```
Order No :
```

I just want if it is not fill by someone then it should not be shown Order No:

Answer (score 1):

Try below way for your requirement.

```
{{depend order_no}}

       Order No : {{var order_no}} 

{{/depend}}
```